# google rich snippets not showing on google search but shows on testing tool

Tags: google-search, google-crawlers, google-ranking

there is a strange problem, i followed each and every step as told in

> http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146897

implementd the review section, hreview aggregate, tested it on richsnippets toll, even this shows correctly:

[image: TESTING TOOL CORRECT RESULT]

But when i go to google and search this page, there is no change, now the questions are:

> 1) What is the problem?
>
> 2) How long google takes to show these changes?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember hearing, Sometimes it can take a few months until Google re-indexes the pages, only then will it show up. For smaller sites it can take longer to re-index, sites with lots of updates are re-indexed more often. Again, that's just what I heard from a friend.

Comment: Even my website have the same problem, so that means if the rich snippet showing the results in webmaster tool, than it means that the code is correct and it gonna appear after some time? thanks.